# Firefox 3.03 and contentEditable

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using the contentEditable attribute on a DIV element in Firefox 3.03.  Setting it to true allows me to edit the text content of the DIV, as expected.

Then, when I set contentEditable to "false", the div is no longer editable, also as expected.

However the flashing caret (text input cursor) remains visible even though the text is no longer editable.  The caret is now also visible when I click on most other text in the same page, even in normal text paragraphs.

Has anyone seen this before?  Is there any way to force the caret hidden?

(When I either resize the browser or click within another application, and come back, the caret magically disappears.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've dealt with this and my workaround is clearing the selection when I disable contentEditable:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) { // replace with browser detection of your choice
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

I am actually removing the "contenteditable" attribute for browsers other than IE, rather than setting it to false:

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
  element.contentEditable = false;
}
else {
  $(element).removeAttr( 'contenteditable' );
}
```

The browsers manage the contentEditable attribute inconsistently and my testing revealed that this worked better overall. I don't remember if this contributed to fixing the caret problem, but I'm throwing it in here just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  removeAllRanges() at least seems to hide the caret after setting conteEditable to false, bit better.  However it comes back again if I click elsewhere on text.  removing the attribute itself didn't seem to ahve any effect.
Might be something Mozilla can fix in a new release.

Comment: A quick search through bugzilla reveals that there is a known bug where setting contentEditable=false triggers caret mode for the whole page. My removing the attribute is a likely reason for why I don't see this bug.

See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433692

Comment: And in Firefox 16 this bug still exists! Removing the attribute doesn't help, but the workaround in this answer does help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute `-moz-user-input` can be used in Firefox to get the functionality  `contenteditable=false` working. 
The value assigned defines if user input is accepted. The possible values are

```
none     : The element does not respond to user input.
enabled  : The element can accepts user input. This is default.
disabled : The element does not accept user input.
```

E.g.:

```
// to disallow users to enter input
<asp:TextBox ID="uxFromDate" runat="server" style="-moz-user-input: disabled;"></asp:TextBox>

// to allow users to enter input
<asp:TextBox ID="uxFromDate" runat="server" style="-moz-user-input: enabled ;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-input for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

This solve the ploblem, looks like firefox is just checking is own way to make things :P

```
 getDoc().designMode  = "off";
```